# On DOM, How it can be calculated which nth level of sibling is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
 <ul>
     <li>first</li>
     <li>second</li>
     <li>third</li>
 </ul>
```

When clicked on second, should alert 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

See it working [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/pbPe9/3/).

Comment: I think index is zero-based, so you need to add +1 to get what Prakash asked? Do you agree?

Comment: using `.index()` will alert 0 on first because of zero-based indexing... http://jsfiddle.net/F6E5K/

Comment: @Tx3 and 3nigma, you're both right, though I realised and edited a while ago ;) Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").click(function() {
  alert("2");
});
```

See it working here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/pbPe9/1/

Good luck!

Comment: Note that in my answer I took your question maybe too literally and it ONLY alerts "2" when clicked on 2, see [Box9's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954409/on-dom-how-it-can-be-calculated-which-nth-level-of-sibling-is-clicked/4954440#4954440) to solve that.